# Experimental proof of gravitational redshift of light

Tags: general-relativity, experimental-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics, gravitational-redshift

Has the gravitational red shift been proven for electromagnetic waves only or also for a single photon?

Answer (score 6):

The first I believe was the [Pound-Rebka experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment) in 1959 in a tower at Harvard.

The best experimental proof we currently have available is the daily successful operation of the G[lobal Positioning System](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrr-2003-1/) (GPS).

Comment: Here I was writing an answer using the same examples. That makes you a party pooper. Pssssstttthhhhhh.... Note that because they used the Mössbauer effect on gamma rays the Rebka and Pound experiment counted discrete photons and of course the GPS system uses EM wave antennas, so both bases are well covered.